# Issues downloading soil organic carbon data from SoilGrids

Tags: r, wcs, soilgrids

I am trying to use R to download soil organic carbon data for a specific region from SoilGrids, using their example code as a start. The code I wrote based on this worked fine to download the sand and clay layers but when I tried the soil organic carbon data it threw errors:

> ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: crs not foundERROR 1:
> msWCSGetCoverage(): WCS server error. Requested BBOX
> (-19949750,8360750,-19949500,8361000) is outside requested coverage
> BBOX (-19949000,-6147500,19861750,8361000)   NULL Warning message: In
> system(cmd, intern = TRUE) :   running command '"C:\Program Files\QGIS
> 3.16.9\bin\gdal_translate.exe" -tr 250 250 -projwin -8666499 -973037 -8553155 -1144861 -of "GTiff" -projwin_srs "+proj=igh +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs" -co "TILED=YES" -co "COMPRESS=DEFLATE" -co "PREDICTOR=2" -co "BIGTIFF=YES" "./sg.xml"
> "./RS_soc_15to30.tif"' had status 1

Wierdly, when I closed R and opened it again it worked for the first layer (0-15cm) but since then it won't do the others, even if I close R or clear the environment. Any ideas what's going wrong? I am very new to R.

This is the code I was running:

```
#Note before loading libraries install the packages
install.packages("XML")
install.packages("rgdal")
install.packages("gdalUtils")
#Might not be necessary to do this again

#load libraries
library(XML)
library(rgdal)
library(gdalUtils)

#Global things
quantile = "Q0.5"
wcs_service = "SERVICE=WCS"
wcs_version = "VERSION=2.0.1" # This works for gdal >=2.3; "VERSION=1.1.1" works with gdal < 2.3.

#Define bounding box (For rough Rio Santa) UL then LR coords
bb=c(-8666499.000,-973037.000,-8553155.000,-1144861.000) # Example bounding box (homolosine)
igh ='+proj=igh +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs' # proj string for Homolosine projection


##For each layer

## Set variables of interest
voi = "soc" # variable of interest
depth = "15-30cm"
voi_layer = paste(voi,depth,quantile, sep="_") # layer of interest 

#We set other variables necessary for the WCS call for all kinds of requests

wcs_path = paste0("https://maps.isric.org/mapserv?map=/map/",voi,".map") # Path to the WCS. See maps.isric.org

#Descirbe the covarage
wcs_request = "DescribeCoverage" 
wcs = paste(wcs_path, wcs_service, wcs_version, wcs_request, sep="&")


#Create XML
l1 <- newXMLNode("WCS_GDAL")
l1.s <- newXMLNode("ServiceURL", wcs, parent=l1)
l1.l <- newXMLNode("CoverageName", voi_layer, parent=l1)

# Save to local disk
xml.out = "./sg.xml"
saveXML(l1, file = xml.out)

gdalinfo("./sg.xml")

# Download raster as GeoTIFF (Warning: it can be large!)
file.out <- './RS_soc_15to30.tif'

gdal_translate(xml.out, file.out,
               tr=c(250,250), projwin=bb,
               projwin_srs =igh, co=c("TILED=YES","COMPRESS=DEFLATE","PREDICTOR=2","BIGTIFF=YES"),
               verbose=TRUE
)
```

Comment: Hi Cat, welcome to GIS.StackExchange, if you haven't done so, please take [the Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn the basics of this web site. Regarding your question, one thing that pops to the eye is the mismatch between the bounding box set with the `bb` variable and that in the error message. Could you verify whether `bb` is actually used in the request?